# error: initializer fails to determine size of ‘K’

Tags: c++

I get the error "`intitializer fails to determine size of 'K'`"at line

```
int K[]= new int[Vertices->total];
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: You need to decide whether you're programming in `C++` or `C`, and, if it's the latter, whether you're using `C99` or not.

Comment: Lousy error message.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @nobugz Actually, I think that's a reasonable error message.

Answer (score 18):

Change

```
int K[]= new int[Vertices->total];
```

to

```
int *K = new int[Vertices->total];
```

The 1st one is the `Java` way of creating an array, where you `K` is a reference to an integer array. But in `C++` we need to make `K` a pointer to integer type.

Comment: @shiva Almost. Arrays in c are really just pointers to blocks of memory. so, if you want to use K to manipulate an array of array of integer, the declaration would be  `int K** = new int*[<count_of_subarrays];´
In the following , you would have to initialize each element of K with `K[i] = new int[<count_of_values>´

Answer (score 3):

`new int[Vertices->total]` returns a pointer and hence, `int *K = new int[Vertices->total];` should work fine.

If you know the size of `Vertices->total` at compile time ( ie CONSTANT)  then you could have used 
`int K[Vertices->total];` // Allocates the memory on stack